# Android Spread buttons equally

Tags: android, android-layout-weight

I am trying to create scrum poker app and I have a problem with spreading image buttons equaly over the screen. It seems that I do not fully understand how particular android layouts work. In fact I used to make it working when I was "drawing" the buttons from an xml file but now I need to use .png files for the image buttons. Here is my layout .xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
style="@style/AppBaseTheme"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity=""
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:background="#f000"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:gravity="top"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    style="@style/lineralLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
    style="@style/lineralLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical">


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout3"
    style="@style/lineralLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical">



</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here are relevant pieces of my code in main activity:

```
public final LinearLayout.LayoutParams rel_btn = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);

private void displayView(int position) {

    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    rel_btn.setMargins(0, 5, 0, 5);

    switch (position) {
    case 0:

        fragment = new StandardFragment();
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();

        linearLayout01 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout01);
        linearLayout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout2);
        linearLayout3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout3);

        linearLayout01.removeAllViews();
        linearLayout2.removeAllViews();
        linearLayout3.removeAllViews();

        layouts = new LinearLayout[3];

        layouts[0] = linearLayout01;
        layouts[1] = linearLayout2;
        layouts[2] = linearLayout3;

        ImageButton[] imageButton = new ImageButton[14];

    for (int i = 0; i < imageButton.length; i++){
        imageButton[i] = new ImageButton(this);
        imageButton[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imageButton[i].setLayoutParams(rel_btn);
        imageButton[i].setId(i+100);
        imageButton[i].setOnClickListener(this);
        imageButton[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        imageButton[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String toParse = "0";
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DuzaKartaActivity.class); 
             intent.putExtra(TEXT_KEY, toParse); 
             startActivity(intent); 
            }
         });
        layouts[i % 3].addView(imageButton[i]);
    }

    imageButton[0].setImageResource(R.drawable.f0);
    imageButton[1].setImageResource(R.drawable.f1);
    imageButton[2].setImageResource(R.drawable.f1_2);
    imageButton[3].setImageResource(R.drawable.f2);
    imageButton[4].setImageResource(R.drawable.f3);
    imageButton[5].setImageResource(R.drawable.f5);
    imageButton[6].setImageResource(R.drawable.f8);
    imageButton[7].setImageResource(R.drawable.f13);
    imageButton[8].setImageResource(R.drawable.f20);
    imageButton[9].setImageResource(R.drawable.f40);
    imageButton[10].setImageResource(R.drawable.f100);
    imageButton[11].setImageResource(R.drawable.infinity);
    imageButton[12].setImageResource(R.drawable.coffee);
    imageButton[13].setImageResource(R.drawable.dont_know);

    Button buttonInvisible = new Button(this, null);

    buttonInvisible.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(),
            R.style.buttonText);
    buttonInvisible.setLayoutParams(rel_btn);
    buttonInvisible
            .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_background_green);
    buttonInvisible.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    linearLayout3.addView(buttonInvisible);

        break;
```

So I would like to have equally spreaded 3 rows of button 5 in each column. The last one is invisible for correct display purpouse. And I would like to scale them depending on device. At the moment I have them displayed quite equally but when I use margins images of those buttons are cutted and if I dont use margins they overlay.

Thanks,
Lenny

EDIT: Here is picture of current output:
[image]

Comment: for weights to work, the weighted size (only one size at a time) of each element must measure **0dp**

Comment: Your advice seems to be working but I still have problems with displaying all of the buttons - right now everything looks fine but the last row which is squeezed.

Comment: I only see 3 LinearLayouts which are weighted. Your Buttons aren't. And please don't make your life (and code) **harder** by implementing Views **in code**, when you can make them **in xml**!

Comment: To be honest I do not have much experience with android. At the beggining I made those buttons defined in xml layout for main activity but then I need to change this layout depending on the user choice therefore I decided to create those buttons dynamically. Is it possible to set weight of buttons through code?

Comment: Yes, but it's more complicate. You could instead prepare different xmls and load the appropriate one depending on the user choice.